# Knocout Js get attribute value inside the custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am using knockout js custom binding, and i am generating the auto index value to generate unique ID its working fine, but i need to get that ID value in my custom bindings, how to achieve this i am unable to do it need help

```
 //this div is inside the for each loop
 before page load
<div data-bind="myFavouriteItem:({Favitem:someitem}),attr: { id: 'Fav_' + $index() }" class="fav"></div>

 after page load get data and ID is generated dynamically
<div data-bind="myFavouriteItem:({Favitem:someitem}),attr: { id: 'Fav_' + $index() }" class="fav"  id="Fav_0"></div>

//custom Binding handler
ko.bindingHandlers.myFavouriteItem= {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
       //inside the consloe.log(element) i am getting above div with ID "Fav_0"
       //here i need to get  the attr ID value
```

}

Comment: Have you tried `element.getAttribute('id')`

Comment: i have tired it,give me null value

Comment: `attr:{ id: 'Fav_'...}` will update `id` of element. So it should work. Can you create a small fiddle where we can test your code?

Comment: then it might be that the bindinghandler is invoked before the div is actually created...

Comment: so any solution for that

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to look into?

Comment: its is solved @thanks,i just change "<div data-bind="attr: { id: 'Fav_' + $index() },myFavouriteItem:({Favitem:someitem})" class="fav"></div>"